# Change Powershell script to send the email with embedded text

Tags: powershell, outlook

I would like to modify the script below, to send the email with embedded text, without removing the html attachments.

The data it should embed into the email is found at: "C:\Users\Users\Summary\SummaryCSV.txt"

Here is the Powershell Script which needs to be modified:

```
 # Check to see we have all the arguments
 If (Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\Users\Summary\SummaryCSV.txt") {
 #Send Email with HTML as attachment and no text embedded
 $FullPath=$args[0] 
 #Get an Outlook application object
 $o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
 $mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
 #2 = High importance message
 $mail.importance = 1
 $mail.subject = "Ready to be retrieved: $(get-date)"
 $mail.body = "Summary $(get-date)"
 #separate multiple recipients with a ";"
 $mail.To = "email@email1.com"
 # Iterate over all files and only add the ones that have an .html extension
 $files = Get-ChildItem $FullPath
 for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
 $outfileName = $files[$i].FullName
 $outfileNameExtension = $files[$i].Extension
 # if the extension is the one we want, add to attachments
 if($outfileNameExtension -eq ".html")
 {
 $mail.Attachments.Add($outfileName);
 }
 } 
 $mail.Send()
 # give time to send the email
 Start-Sleep 5
 # quit Outlook
 $o.Quit()
 #end the script
 #exit
 }
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What version of outlook are you targeting?

Comment: I recommend the `.BodyAsHTML` property to tell Outlook you're using HTML, using `Import-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Html`, and maybe some CSS to make it look nice. You can look at [this blog](https://www.foxdeploy.com/blog/using-html-formatting-to-create-useful-webpage-reports-from-powershell.html) to see about making it look nice, then just set the `.Body` value of your email to be the HTML.

Comment: When you say embedded, I understand that as reading the text file and combining it into the body as text?  You question is not very clear.

Comment: Yes reading the text in the file and adding it to the body, formatted as it is in the .txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your specifications:

```
# Check to see we have all the arguments
If ((Test-Path -Path C:\Users\Users\Summary\SummaryCSV.txt) -and (Test-Path -Path C:\Users\Users\Summary\SummaryCSV.txt)) {
#Send Email with HTML as attachment and no text embedded

$FullPath=$args[0] 
$embeddedText = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Users\Summary\SummaryCSV.txt -Raw

#Get an Outlook application object
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
#2 = High importance message
$mail.importance = 1
$mail.subject = "Ready to be retrieved: $(get-date)"
$mail.body = "Summary $(get-date)`r`n$embeddedText"

#separate multiple recipients with a ";"
$mail.To = "email@email1.com"

# Iterate over all files and only add the ones that have an .html extension
$files = Get-ChildItem $FullPath

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $outfileName = $files[$i].FullName
    $outfileNameExtension = $files[$i].Extension
    # if the extension is the one we want, add to attachments
    if($outfileNameExtension -eq ".html") {
        $mail.Attachments.Add($outfileName);
    }
}

$mail.Send()
# give time to send the email
Start-Sleep 5
# quit Outlook
$o.Quit()
 #end the script
 #exit
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this does work, however the data it is embedding in the email itself, has some lines that are not formatted correctly, not aligned.

Comment: I have marked the above as the solution since it does embed the text into the body albeit the formatting is not exact.  I will open another question and try embedding an html file instead.

Comment: You would do the same thing except read the html file into the string variable and then place the contents into the body property and set the BodyAsHtml to true if memory serves.